# c++ bass and rapidXml on Raspberry Pi 1 B

Tags: c++, xml, raspberry-pi, rapidxml, bass

I have a strange behaviour on a project that I am doing for my kids. I want to parse an xml with rapidXml and play mp3 with bass on my RasPi1B. Everything works fine if I just press it in one main-function. But as soon as I put the code into another class, my xml-data gets corrupted.
I only do c++ in my privat time and work with managed languages, so I am not that into memory-management in c++. So I hope you people can help me (and my kids) out of this issue. Of course I could do everything in just one class, but brain would try to choke me to death ;-)

First of all in a single main function:

```
// test.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <rapidxml.hpp>
#include <rapidxml_utils.hpp>
#include <rapidxml_print.hpp>
#include <bass.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace rapidxml;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    file<> xmlFile("bin/test.xml");

    xml_document<> doc;
    doc.parse<0>(xmlFile.data());

    print(std::cout, doc, 0); // everything is fine

    bool init = BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, NULL);
    cout << "BASS_Init " << (init ? "true" : "false") << " [error: " << BASS_ErrorGetCode() << "]" << endl;

    print(std::cout, doc, 0); // everything is fine

    return 0;
}
```

Then (nearly) the same with a main function and a class/header:

```
//test2.cpp

#include <iostream>

#include "player.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace player;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Player* _pPlayer = new Player();
    _pPlayer->loadXml();

    _pPlayer->printXml();       
    _pPlayer->initPlayer();
    _pPlayer->printXml();

    return 0;
}



// player.cpp

#include "player.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace rapidxml;

namespace player {
    void Player::loadXml(void)
    {
        file<> xmlFile("bin/test.xml");
        doc.parse<0>(xmlFile.data());
    }

    void Player::printXml(void)
    {
        print(std::cout, doc, 0);
    }

    void Player::initPlayer(void)
    {
        bool init = BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, NULL);
        cout << "BASS_Init " << (init ? "true" : "false") << " [error: " << BASS_ErrorGetCode() << "]" << endl;
    }
}



// player.hpp

#include <iostream>

#include <rapidxml.hpp>
#include <rapidxml_utils.hpp>
#include <rapidxml_print.hpp>
#include <bass.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace rapidxml;

namespace player {
    class Player
    {
        public:
            void loadXml(void);
            void printXml(void);
            void initPlayer(void);
        private:
            xml_document<> doc;
    };
}
```

Compiling with:

```
BASS_PATH = ../libraries/bass_arm
BASS_INCLUDE_PATH = -I$(BASS_PATH)
BASS_LIBRARY_PATH = -L$(BASS_PATH) -L$(BASS_PATH)/hardfp
BASS_LIBS = -lbass -lm
BASS_LINKER_FLAGS = -Wl,-rpath,$(BASS_PATH):$(BASS_PATH)/hardfp

RAPIDXML_PATH = ../libraries/rapidxml-1.13
RAPIDXML_INCLUDE_PATH = -I$(RAPIDXML_PATH)
RAPIDXML_LIBRARY_PATH = -L$(RAPIDXML_PATH)

test:
    g++ -std=c++11 src_test/test.cpp -o bin/test $(BASS_INCLUDE_PATH) $(RAPIDXML_INCLUDE_PATH) $(BASS_LIBRARY_PATH) $(RAPIDXML_LIBRARY_PATH) $(BASS_LIBS) $(BASS_LINKER_FLAGS)

test2:
    g++ -std=c++11 -g -c src_test/test2.cpp -o src_test/test2.o $(BASS_INCLUDE_PATH) $(RAPIDXML_INCLUDE_PATH)
    g++ -std=c++11 -g -c src_test/player.cpp -o src_test/player.o $(BASS_INCLUDE_PATH) $(RAPIDXML_INCLUDE_PATH)
    g++ -std=c++11 -g src_test/test2.o src_test/player.o -o bin/test2 $(BASS_LIBRARY_PATH) $(RAPIDXML_LIBRARY_PATH) $(BASS_LIBS) $(BASS_LINKER_FLAGS)
```

My test.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<library>
    <series>
        <title>Lorem ipsum A</title>
        <episode>
            <title>dolor sit amet 1</title>
            <cover></cover>
            <files rfid="x1" current_file="1" timestamp="0">
                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_11.mp3</file>
                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_12.mp3</file>
                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_13.mp3</file>
                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_14.mp3</file>
            </files>
        </episode>
        <episode>
            <title>dolor sit amet 2</title>
            <cover></cover>
            <files rfid="x2" current_file="1" timestamp="0">
                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_21.mp3</file>
                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_22.mp3</file>
                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_23.mp3</file>
                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_24.mp3</file>
            </files>
        </episode>
    </series>
</library>
```

And here is the output of **sudo bin/test**

```
<library>
        <series>
                <title>Lorem ipsum A</title>
                <episode>
                        <title>dolor sit amet 1</title>
                        <cover/>
                        <files rfid="x1" current_file="1" timestamp="0">
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_11.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_12.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_13.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_14.mp3</file>
                        </files>
                </episode>
                <episode>
                        <title>dolor sit amet 2</title>
                        <cover/>
                        <files rfid="x2" current_file="1" timestamp="0">
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_21.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_22.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_23.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_24.mp3</file>
                        </files>
                </episode>
        </series>
</library>
BASS_Init true [error: 0]
<library>
        <series>
                <title>Lorem ipsum A</title>
                <episode>
                        <title>dolor sit amet 1</title>
                        <cover/>
                        <files rfid="x1" current_file="1" timestamp="0">
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_11.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_12.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_13.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_14.mp3</file>
                        </files>
                </episode>
                <episode>
                        <title>dolor sit amet 2</title>
                        <cover/>
                        <files rfid="x2" current_file="1" timestamp="0">
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_21.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_22.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_23.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_24.mp3</file>
                        </files>
                </episode>
        </series>
</library>
```

And the output of **sudo bin/test2**:

```
<library>
        <series>
                <title>Lorem ipsum A</title>
                <episode>
                        <title>dolor sit amet 1</title>
                        <cover/>
                        <files rfid="x1" current_file="1" timestamp="0">
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_11.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_12.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_13.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_14.mp3</file>
                        </files>
                </episode>
                <episode>
                        <title>dolor sit amet 2</title>
                        <cover/>
                        <files rfid="x2" current_file="1" timestamp="0">
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_21.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_22.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_23.mp3</file>
                                <file>consetetur/sadipscing_elitr_24.mp3</file>
                        </files>
                </episode>
        </series>
</library>

BASS_Init true [error: 0]
<l1▒B>
        CJ>
                <>▒CJ▒BJ▒BJ</>
                <device>
                        <de>aults.pcm.device</de>
                        <`CJ/>
                        <8CJ BJ="" iec958="1" 1▒CJ="">
                                <>▒DJ▒BJ6Jcardp3</>
                                <ults>pcm.cardr/1▒CJ▒CJ</ults>
                                <▒CJ>devicesg_edefault</▒CJ>
                                <1>DJPDJ▒CJ(DJ▒CJ</1>
                        </8CJ>
                </device>
                <EJpE>
                        <▒>J▒CJ6J</▒>
                        <cover/>
                        <cm.ca did="" J▒DJ="" pEJ="J">
                                <>devicesdipdefaults.pcm.d</>
                                <>@EJ▒DJEJ▒DJ</>
                                <rmat>rawur/sadip1▒EJ▒EJ</rmat>
                                <▒DJ>6Jtrueltstr_fi</▒DJ>
                        </cm.ca>
                </EJpE>
        <CJ>
</l1▒B>
```

Sorry for the long post! I hope someone can help me. I feel really lost... 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmlFile` gets destroyed when `Player::loadXml()` goes out of scope. This allows the memory that is occupied by the data of `xmlFile` to be assigned to something else (in this case `BASE_Init` seems to be writing data to it).

`doc` is still using the data that `xmlFile` used to be. This leads to undefined behavior.

Please store `xmlFile` in the `Player` class, like you did with `doc`.

Also don't forget to `delete` everything you `new`, like _pPlayer ;-)

Comment: oh yeah, you made my day! I thought all the time, that xmlFile isn't used after doc.parse()...
Even though, this rapidxml_utils (where file<> is defined) gave me some hard minutes too, because I didn't knew how to handle the whole template-stuff (not in templates yet, but looks a bit like generics in java).
I solved it by adding `file<>* pXmlFile;` to the **.hpp** and `pXmlFile = new file<>("bin/test.xml");` to the **.cpp**.
Works fine so far, but is it the right way?
(edit: poor formatting-options in comments ^^)

Comment: Also as an addition: yes, in my "production code" I use `delete`. I just wanted to keep the example as short as possible.

Comment: Using a pointer to a `file<>*` is **a** right way. Another way could be without pointers, using the constructor of `Player` to initialize your `file<> xmlFile`. After the `public:` in your `Player` class, you could add: `Player() : xmlFile("bin/test.xml") {}`

Comment: Thanks again! I can live with **a** right way ;-) I know there is most of the time more than one good way. I intentionally didn't used the constructor-approach, because in the "real" program the loaded xml varies on which user uses the app. But yes, I also thought about this solution. Anyways, pointer is working like a charm and I am very happy to continue working effectively on my little project. I tried solving this bug for almost 3 weeks (not every day and only in the evening... but it went to be annoying). So a last time I have to say: thank you very much!